# Escaping single quotes in a bash script command

Tags: bash, scripting, escape-characters

I am trying to write a script which has to execute a command containing single quotes in it. This is the command I am trying to execute in the script:

```
srt-live-transmit udp://224.0.0.0:1234 'srt://@1111?passphrase=thisisatest&latency=500' -v
```

And this is my `BASH` shell script's command:

```
srt-live-transmit $MC srt://${SRT_IP}:${SRT_PORT}?${LATENCY}&${PASS} -v
```

As you can see the `SRT` path is in single quotes in order for the command to accept my both parameters: `passphrase` and `latency`. I have tried to escape the single quote with `\'`, `'\''`, `'"'"'`, `$\'` but the command is either not executed or the `SRT` path is without single quotes when I grep for the process in the process list.

Comment: "nothing seemed to work" ... what error message do you get? What is the actual issue here?

Comment: it just my command is either not executed or the SRT path is without the single quotes.

Comment: @GeorgеStoyanov why? I mean, why don't you run the command exactly as you show it? Why is any escaping needed? Is that command in a variable or is it just a line in your script?

Comment: Why do you think that you need to pass the _literal_ single quotes to the `srt-live-transmit` command?  Yes, you need to use quotes to protect the `&` from the shell, but that's that. The shell will _remove_ the single quotes from the argument once it is parsed, just as in `echo 'hello & goodbye'`.  Your command, as written, ought to work. Please explain what does not work.

Comment: "when I grep for the process in the process list" ... when you run `some-command 'foo-bar'`, the shell removes the quotes. They won't show up in the process list.

Comment: when I execute `ps -ax | grep srt` I can still see the single quotes if I execute it independently and if I execute it in the `BASH` script I don't see them.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have updated my original post with a bit more details what exactly is not working.

Comment: You are not supposed to see the single quotes. `srt-live-transmit` doesn't need them; they are just for the shell and will not appear in `ps` in typical setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, and your variables contain what I *guess* they contain (next time, please show us what the variables' values are and how you assign them), then all you need is quoting:

```
srt-live-transmit "$MC" "srt://${SRT_IP}:${SRT_PORT}?${LATENCY}&${PASS}" -v
```

You can't really escape single quotes in a single-quoted string, but you can just use double quotes, which allow variables to be expanded, instead.